# Suppress Lint warning for hardcoded strings inside "Log.v(TAG, ...)"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

I'm asking myself if there is a possibility for suppressing the lint warning "hardcoded string" in the case that the hardcoded string is the argument of the logging method "Log.v(tag, msg)"...

For debugging i'm using the logging but i don't want to outsource these strings in the ressource file...

Thx for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing but as a fallback, I do know you can add //NON-NLS to each line containing an hardcoded string. They will then be ignored by the lint validation. Although, this solution is far from optimal when you have thousands of files to change. The ideal option would be to redefine the Hard coded strings lint validation rules..